trying to duplicate bones in edit mode with python
I copied some code from a similar thread but it seems my implementation is not working.
import bpy
import copy

def duplicate_bones(bones, current_armature, prefix):
    prefix += '_'
    for bone in bones:
        bone_name = prefix + bone.name
        new_bone = current_armature.bones.new(bone_name)
        new_bone.copy(bone)

def execute():
    current_armature = bpy.context.active_object
    current_bones = current_armature.data.bones
    prefix = 'CTRL'
    duplicate_bones(current_bones, current_armature, prefix)
execute()

While in edit mode with 2 bones selected this code throws this error.
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/alexandria/Documents/3d/AddonDev/tutorial.blend/Demos.py", line 16, in <module>
   File "/Users/alexandria/Documents/3d/AddonDev/tutorial.blend/Demos.py", line 15, in execute
   File "/Users/alexandria/Documents/3d/AddonDev/tutorial.blend/Demos.py", line 8, in duplicate_bones
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'bones'


did you select your armature before running the code?

I was in edit mode, and I selected 2 bones.

I think you meant to reference current_armature.data.bones on line 8, but you referenced current_armature.bones instead, which is invalid: The armature object has no bones attribute, only its armature data block or its pose data block do.
Another problem on that same line is that Armature.bones has no new() method. Armature.edit_bones does, though, so I think that is what you were looking for there as well.
See the Blender Python API docs for more info.

New error with that
AttributeError: bpy_prop_collection: attribute "new" not found


@victoriaisabellaamos That's technically another question, so it should really be asked separately, but I can see that you're a bit lost in the Blender API (I've added a docs link to the answer), or just Python in general. I'm looking around for how to create a new bone, but I'm concerned this is going to be constant whack-a-mole. Stackexchange isn't so much for first learning questions.
